# retrieve the Service value from the text input

Tags: regex

Need to extract the value from the text input which will be in following format:

```
Tom Felton (tfelton@example.com) notified you about this incident:
Incident : TESTING INTEGRATION - P1
Status: active | Severity: SEV-1 | Service: Test Service 1 | Commander: Tom Felton
https://app.testapp.com
`your text`
```

From above text we want to fetch the value of the Service.
How can we use regular expression to get the Service value.

I tried using following script:

```
var msg = incGR.description;  //msg variable holds the input text
//var re = /Severity:\s([0-9])/g;
// var m = re.exec(source.text_only_msg);
var regex = /Service: \s([a-zA-Z0-9])/g;
var m = msg.match(regex);
// If there is no match, m will be null;
if (m) {

    if (m.length == 2) {
        severity = m[1];
    }
}
gs.info("severity: "+ severity); //printing Service here
```

Comment: Please indicate which programming language you are using as well by tagging the question

Comment: You put an extra space after `Service:`, also it looks like the name of `Service` may also contain white spaces, so `[a-zA-Z0-9]` could not match the whole text. Try something like [`Service:\s*([^|]*?)(?=\s*(?:\||$))`](https://regex101.com/r/Xe8AxQ/latest)

Comment: Or just `Service:\s*([^|]+?)\s*\|` it is always in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a JS expert. The best I could come out with is this (which gives you the result you want):

```js
text = "Tom Felton (tfelton@example.com) notified you about this incident:\
Incident : TESTING INTEGRATION - P1\
Status: active | Severity: SEV-1 | Service: Test Service 1 | Commander: Tom Felton\
https://app.testapp.com\
`your text`"
var regex = /\bService:\s(.*)\|/g;
var m = text.matchAll(regex);
var v = m.next().value[1];
console.log(v);
```

Even though in Python and many other languages that regex would return exactly the service value, but in JS it's kinda more complicated than that, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/432503/18926992).

Answer (score 0):

You are matching a space AND a whitespace char with  `\s` but you only have a single space. You are also not repeating the character class, and it could will only match a single character like that.

If you only want to match single spaces and the specified characters in the character class, you can get the value from capture group 1, denoted as `m[1]`

The pattern `/\bService: ([a-z0-9]+(?: [a-z0-9]+)*)\b/i` with a flag for a case insensitive match:

- `\bService:`  The word `Service` followed by `:`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[a-z0-9]+` Match 1 or more of the specified charrs
  - `(?: [a-z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat a single space followed by one or more of the specified chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `\b` A word boundary

```js
var msg = `Tom Felton (tfelton@example.com) notified you about this incident:
Incident : TESTING INTEGRATION - P1
Status: active | Severity: SEV-1 | Service: Test Service 1 | Commander: Tom Felton
https://app.testapp.com`;
var regex = /\bService: ([a-z0-9]+(?: [a-z0-9]+)*)\b/i;
var m = msg.match(regex);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

---

Another option could be matching the whitespace char followed by at least a single char a-zA-Z0-9, and then optionally match chars other than a pipe ending on a non whitespace char other than a pipe.

```
\bService:\s([a-zA-Z0-9](?:[^|]*[^\s|])?)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xoJLEC/1).